# Pressure drop across orifice plate

Tags: fluid-mechanics, pressure, fluid

I have been trying to estimate pressure loss caused by an orifice plate. The fluid flowing through it would be water.

I found equations for discharge efficient and pressure loss coefficient K from ISO 5167-2 (2003, pages 11 and 13). Can I calculate the loss from this equation (also page 13): $k = \frac{loss}{\frac{1}{2}\rho_1 V^2}$.
Am I using these equations in the wrong place? I'm trying to educate myself and learn more about the theory of these things.

Comment: Try Mechanics of Fluids by Massey - a good explanation in that.

Comment: Purpose of the standards is not to educate, so basis of some calculations may be obfuscated. In terms of education, the standards can show you what is actually used in practice, but you may have a hard time to learn from them why it is used. For this, books and papers are generally better.